# Chrome Extension Modifying User Agent

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to modify the user agent from within a chrome extension?

I am developing an extension for web developers (yes I'm aware of Chromes own extension for this).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Example code changing the User-Agent for an Android one.

```
var MOBILE_CHROME_USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android-4.0.3; en-us; Galaxy Nexus Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) CrMo/16.0.912.75 Mobile Safari/535.7';
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(details) {
        for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
            if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'User-Agent') {
                details.requestHeaders[i].value = MOBILE_CHROME_USER_AGENT;
                break;
            }
        }
        return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
    }, {urls: ['<all_urls>']}, ['blocking', 'requestHeaders']);
```

Comment: Works great! Be sure to include `webRequest` and `webRequestBlocking` in your manifest permissions, otherwise chrome.webRequest will be undefined

Comment: Some websites also look for javascript user agents. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202136/changing-navigator-useragent-using-chrome-extension to change that in extensions as well

Answer (score 2):

The WebRequest API is no longer experimental; You can read all about it at its new home:
[chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html)

and yes you can use it to alter the `User-Agent` header.

Answer (score 0):

There's experimental [WebRequest API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.webRequest.html) for these purposes. You can prevent URL requests, change request headers etc. Of course you can't yet upload your extension to Chrome Web Store if your code uses experimental features of Chrome extensions.