# Change navigator in browser to pretend, that plugin is installed (with javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, navigator

I am trying to do Chrome extension, that will pretend, that some plugins are installed. I was trying to edit navigator.plugins, but these properties are read-only. I can add new item navigator.plugins[x], but I do not know, how to create new (Plugin, PluginArray or MimeType) objects in navigator.plugins.

Is it even possible ?

Comment: What about doing it in the similar fashion as [Changing navigator.userAgent using Chrome Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23202136) ?

Comment: I do not have a problem to change useragent, because it is simple value,  but I am not sure, how to create objects like - Plugin, PluginArray or MimeType in navigator.plugins

Comment: Ah, just reuse the existing object's prototype like `var plugin = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(navigator.plugins[0]))`

Comment: @wOxxOm If I write this - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4hc7mons/) to the console, it will create type Object, it does not help me, because I need type Plugin [link](http://i.imgsafe.org/ddbb0cf.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried cracking it but failed. Apparently `Plugin` type can't be instantiated manually. It's read-only by specification and Chrome implements it accordingly ([source code](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/modules/plugins/Plugin.idl&sq=package:chromium&dr=C)). As you can see the constructor is not exposed to DOM, so we can't use `new Plugin` or other methods to instantiate it.

On the other hand you can try [injecting the code into webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) via `<script>` element, for example, that will replace the entire built-in `Plugin` class with your own implementation and use that fake class to populate `navigator.plugins`. Ditto for `PluginArray`.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an approach that works quite well for spoofing the PluginArray (notice the `Object.setPrototypeOf`):

```
(function generatePluginArray() {
  const pluginData = [
    { name: "Chrome PDF Plugin", filename: "internal-pdf-viewer", description: "Portable Document Format" },
    { name: "Chrome PDF Viewer", filename: "mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai", description: "" },
    { name: "Native Client", filename: "internal-nacl-plugin", description: "" },
  ]
  const pluginArray = []
  pluginData.forEach(p => {
    function FakePlugin () { return p }
    const plugin = new FakePlugin()
    Object.setPrototypeOf(plugin, Plugin.prototype);
    pluginArray.push(plugin)
  })
  Object.setPrototypeOf(pluginArray, PluginArray.prototype);
  return pluginArray
})()
```

Console output:

[image]

<s>I haven't added the MimeType property yet, but that should be accomplishable in a similar manner.</s>

Feel free to submit a PR in case you flesh this out (I've developed a plugin for puppeteer that's implementing various detection evasion techniques):
https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth

Edit: I've had some spare time and added code to fully emulate `navigator.plugins` and `navigator.mimeTypes` [here](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth/evasions/navigator.plugins). It even mocks functional methods, instance types and .toString properties, to make them look native and resemble a normal Google Chrome.

Comment: Detect headless mode are very easy. Fake navigator object are useless.