# Custom Navigator overwritten after document load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a simple Chrome extension that tries to spoof your current user agent. I just found out about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202136/changing-navigator-useragent-using-chrome-extension/23456845#23456845) and implemented it in my code.

The following is a content script that tries to replace the current user agent string, set to run at `document_start`:

```
let useragent, actualCode, timer = null;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.useragent) {
    sendResponse({error: false});
    useragent = request.useragent;
  }
  else sendResponse({error: true});
});

var receivedUA = function() {
  if (useragent != null) {
    window.clearInterval(timer);
    actualCode = function(userAgent) {
      console.log('im being called');
      'use strict';
      let navigator = window.navigator;
      let modifiedNavigator;

      if ('userAgent' in Navigator.prototype) {
        modifiedNavigator = Navigator.prototype;
      } else {
        modifiedNavigator = Object.create(navigator);
        Object.defineProperty(window, 'navigator', {
          value: modifiedNavigator,
          configurable: false,
          enumerable: false,
          writable: false
        });
        Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'navigator', {
          value: modifiedNavigator,
          configurable: false,
          enumerable: false,
          writable: false
        });
      }

      Object.defineProperties(modifiedNavigator, {
        userAgent: {
          value: userAgent.useragent,
          configurable: false,
          enumerable: true,
          writable: false
        },
        appVersion: {
          value: userAgent.appversion,
          configurable: false,
          enumerable: true,
          writable: false
        },
        platform: {
          value: userAgent.platform,
          configurable: false,
          enumerable: true,
          writable: false
        }
      });

      console.dir(modifiedNavigator);

    };
    let evt = new Event('reset');
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('reset', actualCode(useragent));
    document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(evt);
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('reset', actualCode(useragent));
  }
  else {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = window.setTimeout(receivedUA, 100);
  }
}
receivedUA();
```

However, I'm testing on whatsmyua.com and the code is called when the document starts to load, but after it has loaded, it displays my true user agent, and typing `window.navigator.userAgent` on the console returns the same. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should avoid such complexity with using `chrome.webRequest` API [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). Here is a bit modified example  which will output User-Agent header's object from the link above:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(details) {
        for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
            if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'User-Agent') {
              console.log(details.requestHeaders[i]);
              break;
            }
          }
          return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]
);
```

Also.. you should add this into your background script (see [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages))

Comment: I think part of answering the question is explaining why it didn't work, specially since your suggestion won't affect `window.navigator`

Comment: I already use this part in my code. I think the vast majority of websites rely on `window.navigator` to retrieve the user agent instead of the HTTP headers.

Comment: So, is there anything I can do to prevent it from being overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

If you check source code of the http://www.whatsmyua.com/ you can see that it gets user-agent at the page loading in inline scripts at the beginning of the body:

`function getUa() {
   return decodeURIComponent(location.hash.replace('#', '')) || navigator.userAgent;
}`

So the answer here is timing: who will be faster - your content-script or page scripts.
And the page is winning. It retrieves user-agent before content-script overrides it.

You can download the page as html, run it on localhost and put there additional logging with timestamps to measure timings.

Also make sure you're using `"run_at": "document_start"` for your context script.